# Good explanation of ruby object model -- mainly, 'classes are objects'?

Tags: ruby

I am studying the ruby object model and have some questions. I understand the idea that an object only stores instance variables, and methods are stored in the class, which an object has a reference to. I also understand the idea of 'self' -- what it is, how it changes, etc.

However, what I don't understand is the notion that 'classes are objects.' Is there a good, intuitive explanation anywhere?

(BTW: I'm using [Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming) and [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) as my two resources. If anybody can suggest something else, that would be helpful.)

Thanks.

Comment: After some time with Ruby, I came to completely opposite question: how come that we buy into languages where classes are NOT objects...

Comment: Try "The Well-Grounded Rubyist" by David Black -- http://www.manning.com/black2/

Answer (score 12):

It means precisely what it sounds like — classes are objects. Specifically, they are instances of the class `Class`, which is itself a subclass of the class `Module`, which in turn is a subclass of `Object`, just like every other class in Ruby. Like any other object in Ruby, a class can respond to messages, have its own instance variables, etc.

As a practical example, let's take `private`.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :height
  private
  attr_accessor :weight
end
```

This gives instances of Person public methods to access the person's name and height, but the accessors for the person's weight are private. BUTBUTBUT — rather than being a keyword like in most languages, `private` is an ordinary method of the Module class. If we wanted, we could redefine it to do something different for a particular class hierarchy.

```
class RichardStallman
  def self.private(*args)
    puts "NO! INFORMATION WAS MEANT TO BE FREE!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's my shot at one.

In Ruby, classes are objects.  Usually they have class `Class`.  For example, let's consider the class `Foo`.

```
class Foo
end
```

Doubtless you've seen this before, and it's not terribly exciting.  But we could also have defined `Foo` this way:

```
Foo = Class.new
```

Just as you'd create a new `Foo` by calling `Foo.new`, you can create a new `Class` by calling `Class.new`.  Then you give that class the name `Foo` by assigning it, just like any other variable.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 6):

The notion of "classes are objects"  ( as I understand it ) implies that anything you can do with an object, you can do it with a class.

This differs from other programming languages where the class and the class definition are special artifacts different from objects and often unaccessible to the runtime.

For instance in Ruby, you can modify any object at runtime, since classes are also objects you can modify the class it self and add methods at runtime, delete methods, or add and delete attributes at runtime.

For instance:

```
$ irb
>> x = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x1011ce560>
>> x.to_s
=> "#<Object:0x1011ce560>"
>> undef to_s
=> nil
>> x.to_s
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_s' for #<Object:0x1011ce560>
from (irb):4
>>
```

That's not possible on other programming languages where a distinction between objects and classes is made.

note: Probably you should understand basic Ruby concepts before going to meta programming as it may be confusing, that what I would do.

Comment: It's worth noting that many other languages *do* have this feature (notably, Smalltalk; many other languages borrow from there).

Comment: Actually Ruby took this from Smalltalk

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article, you may find it helpful:

[The Ruby Object Model - Structure and Semantics](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html)

Personally I learned a lot about the Ruby object model by reading about the Smalltalk one (e.g. in the [Squeak](http://squeak.org/) documentation). And depending on how fluent you are in C, the MRI sources are quite approachable and yield the most definite answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you think of it, it's completely logical for `new` to be a function, right? A function which creates and returns a new object. (Unlike most of other languages where `new` is some kind of operator or a language construct.)

Pushing it further, even more logical for this function `new` is that it should be a method, if we are talking about an OO language. Whose method? A method of an object, just a little bit different sort of an object that we can call "class".

So, looking it that way, classes are just special kinds of objects, objects that, among other peculiarities, have method `new` and know how to create other objects based on their own image.

Answer (score 0):

> what I don't understand is the notion that 'classes are objects.' Is there a good, intuitive explanation anywhere?

[An answer to SO thread `Visual representation of Ruby Object Model'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75229441/463206) links to an excellent video on the subject.