# Visual representation of Ruby Object Model

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a visual representation of the Ruby Object Model. This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

I was wondering if my depiction of the Kernel module is acceptable or not, or is there a better way to illustrate it (or any other part of the model)

Comment: What about the eigenclass of p1?

Comment: @SagarPandya yes should add that for completeness.

Comment: [Take your pick!](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ruby+object+model&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA752CA752&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj-d7vg4jVAhUN5mMKHYWPCG8QsAQILA&biw=1098&bih=488).

Comment: Why `klass` here?

Comment: You may also want to differentiate between "is a subclass of" with "inherits methods from" as well as "is eigenclass of" by labelling the arrows. Those oval insets seem to imply those things are contained within rather than properties of.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to illustrate it (or any other part of the model)

[Here is an excellent presentation on the Ruby Object Model](https://youtu.be/X2sgQ38UDVY).

The presentation's money quote:

> Everything in Ruby is an object. Object is a class; Class itself is an object.

[That quote](https://youtu.be/X2sgQ38UDVY?t=648) is accompanied by a text-based diagram right out of ruby source code. It is a visual [klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)  of confusion.

WATCH THE WHOLE VIDEO.  [At the end you'll feel like Neo](https://youtu.be/6vMO3XmNXe4?t=8) - "I know Ruby Object Model!"

---

Dave Thomas, the speaker, is an original signer of the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](https://agilemanifesto.org). Look up his presentation on "the death of agile". Very interesting.